# apache + wsgi + django : Client denied by server configuration

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, http-status-code-403

I'm getting a **403** error with my django project.

The only line I get in my error log is :

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /srv/http/www/src/myproject/preprod_wsgi.py
```

The permissions for this file are :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  552 Jul 30 04:24 preprod_wsgi.py
```

And the apache (VERSION : 2.4) conf file contains (amongst other things) :

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
    User http
    Group http
</IfModule>

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Others
#

Alias /robots.txt /srv/http/www/htdocs/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /srv/http/www/htdocs/static/favicon.ico


Alias /media/ /srv/http/www/htdocs/media/
Alias /static/ /srv/http/www/htdocs/static/


<Directory "/srv/http/www/htdocs/static">
           Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/srv/http/www/htdocs/media">
           Require all granted
</Directory>

<Files "/srv/http/www/src/myproject/preprod_wsgi.py">
       Require all granted
</Files>

#
# WSGI
#

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/srv/http/www/src
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/http/www/src/myproject/preprod_wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /srv/http/www/src

DocumentRoot "/srv/http/www/htdocs"
<Directory "/srv/http/www/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog "/srv/http/www/logs/error_log"
CustomLog "/srv/http/www/logs/access_log" common

LogLevel warn
```

Here is also the content of my **preprod_wsgi.py** file :

```
"""
WSGI config for soisbault project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.preprod_settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

`ALLOWED_HOSTS` is also set in my `preprod_settings.py`.

I tried to add access to this file with `<Files>` directive, and did a `chmod 755` on it. But I can't figure out what I could do more.

How could I fix this? Feel free to ask more details if necessary.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is the file (and presumably the rest of the project) owned by root?

Comment: Please have a look at [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Good question. the whole project is in a docker container, I guess that the project's ownership was set at its copy during container building. But I runned a `chown -Rv http` and restarted the service and I still get this error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman (Anyway, with 755 permission, shouldn't httpd be able to execute the wsgi.py script even if it's owned by root?)

Comment: Are you sure that you have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['yourhost.com']` set in your django settings file, that will throw a 403 otherwise if debug is turned off.

Comment: @Mischback I already did and I didn't find what I could have forgot, do you think about something in particular?

Comment: @olofom It could have been it, indeed, but in my case ALLOWED_HOSTS is set, I'll update my post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems it was the **<File>** directive in apache that can't be used outside of a **<Directory>** directive.

```
<Files "/srv/http/www/src/myproject/preprod_wsgi.py">
       Require all granted
</Files>
```

I changed this to

```
<Directory "/srv/http/www/src/myproject">
       <Files "preprod_wsgi.py">
              Require all granted
       </Files>
</Directory>
```

And it worked. :)